# Suppress Resharper warning in C# code if containing function has a certain attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, annotations, resharper, suppress

We are having some false positives in our code saying "Possible System.NullRefrenceException".
The methods in which the errors occur are marked with a [CustomAuthorizeAttribute] that inherits from [AuthorizeAttribute]. In AuthorizeCore() of the implementation of CustomAuthorizeAttribute, we call the same function and return false if the the return value is null.

Here is the code:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute] // AuthorizeCore returns false if GetUser(HttpContext) returned null
public ActionResult Get()
{
    var user = GetUser(HttpContext);

    if (user.HasFeatureX) // Possible System.NullReferenceException
    {
    ...
    }
    ...

}

[CanBeNull]
public static User GetUser([NotNull] HttpContextBase context)
{
... 
}

protected override sealed bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (GetUser(m_)context) == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So if we are getting into the function, we already have checked that our user is not null. In conclusion, the Resharper warning is a false positive.

Is there an easy way to suppress such kind of false positives via attributes or something similar?
Or does the solution of this problem require a plugin or additional code?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an assertion that user isn't `null` before `if (user.HasFeatureX)`.
ReSharper will probably suggest the fix for you.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility, at least when Resharper is run in Debug configuration. But that would still mean that I have to mark each occurrence by hand. I was looking for something that works automatically dependending on the attribute.